# React Native conditional state in onPress render any time without press component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, touchableopacity, onpress

Why is this onPress activated at any time without pressing TouchableOpacity when I change any property of state if project_id is not null?

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    if (this.state.feedback.project_id != null) {
      this.setModalVisible(true);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Select a project please');
    }
  }}>
  <View>
    <Text>SEND NOW</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Example process:

1. I press this touchable and project_id == 1 , modal will open.
2. I close the modal
3. I change feedback.name with a textinput
4. Because project_id is still 1 modal will open

Comment: Can you be more specific please ? I am lost after you close the modal.
"3- I change feedback.name with a textinput 4- Because project_id is still 1 modal will open" <-- i didnt understand this one

Comment: @Cookie please the relevant code.

Comment: Now I see that the problem is another...
I active the modal in this screen, but modal is an import component that I do visible or  invisible in this import, and in first screen modalvisible remains true
On close modal I would have to change fist screen, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: I can not help you until you provide me more source code and being "CLEAR" on that issue.

Comment: I create a new question to explain myself better

Comment: look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662641/react-native-change-state-of-screen-when-close-import-modal